# [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String in LDAP Search

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

When i am trying to search password of user from ldap server this
below error displayed

In this code its doesn't return user Password in String.  It throws

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Code:

```
public class selectEntry {

        DirContext ldapContext = null;

        public selectEntry() {
            try {
                Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
                environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
                environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, conntype);
                environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, AdminDn);
                environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

                ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(environment);

                System.out.println("Bind successful");
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void getEntry() {
            try {
                SearchControls searcCon = new SearchControls();
                searcCon.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
                NamingEnumeration results
                        = ldapContext.search("uid=aruhat.aruhat,ou=openzki,dc=aruhat,dc=co,dc=in", "(uid=aruhat.aruhat)", searcCon);
                if (results != null) {
                    while (results.hasMore()) {
                        SearchResult res = (SearchResult) results.next();
                        Attributes atbs = res.getAttributes();
                        Attribute atb = atbs.get("userPassword");
                        String name = (String) atb.get();
                       System.out.println("Name is :=> " + name);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("fail");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception Type:=> "+e);
                System.out.println("Exception Message:=> "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new selectEntry().getEntry();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems the user password is stored as a `byte[]`. You have to convert that to a String somehow. Maybe `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: Or, you are just looking at the wrong attribute. Don't you want `"userName"`?

Comment: no i am looking for user's password not user name ,attribute is right

Comment: Then you have to work with that `byte[]`. But it would be bad practice for the LDAP to store the password, so the attribute is probably just a binary hash (not something you can print in a meaningful way).

Comment: I just want to check the password in this program=> if user want to change his password then his updating password must be different than  previous old one so I am getting old password of logged user from this method

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: If your admin happen to store passwords in plain text in your directory server, I would fire him immediately.

Comment: Thanks a lot error solved

Comment: Solved how? Not much use to anyone else unless you tell us.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Retreiving binary attributes requires the `;binary` suffix, e.g., `userCertificate;binary`. Then you have the `Attribute` object. Invoke

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[]) attr.get()
```

and you are done. Don't work with `toString()` or `(String)` cast.

Comment: The `;binary` causes `String` attributes to be returned as `byte[]`. This one already is binary.

Comment: Still wrong. The value is already a `byte[]`, even without `;binary`, and he is not using `toString()`.

Comment: But i have `<125` reputation score in stackoverflow so i cant up or down vote sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

LDAP passwords are stored as hashes, not strings. The attribute value is returned as a `byte[]`, as the exception says.

However you don't have any good reason for obtaining the hashed password attribute in the first place. It won't do you any good. Review your requirement. You should be binding as the user using the old password to test whether it's valid, not trying to read the password, which you won't get.